# Derive a field based on most recent value present within a group

Tags: sql, oracle

I'll appreciate if I can direction on how to go about deriving this new field NAME1 based on the ID group and Date. Thanks

```
Have

ID Name DeptID  Date
1  Junh  junk   19990101
1  John  junk1  19990202
1  JOHN  CLEAN  20200101
2  David junk   19990101
2  John  junk1  19990202
2  DAVID GOOD   20200101

WANT

ID Name DeptID Date        NAME1
1  Junh  junk   19990101   JOHN
1  John  junk1  19990202   JOHN
1  JOHN  CLEAN  20200101   JOHN
2  David junk   19990101   DAVID
2  John  junk1  19990202   DAVID
2  DAVID GOOD   20200101   DAVID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Tim's answer, but another option to consider is something like the following:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.Name,
    t1.DeptID,
    t1."Date",
    max(t1.name) keep (dense_rank first order by t1."Date" DESC) OVER (partition by t1.ID) as Name1
FROM yourtable t1
ORDER BY
    t1.ID,
    t1."Date"
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach, using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.Name,
    t1.DeptID,
    t1.Date,
    t2.Name AS NAME1
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE
    t2.rn = 1
ORDER BY
    t1.ID,
    t1.Date;
```

Comment: Was working on the same query so here's a demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0aa716d160fb6f86f599273e9fc8e1b5

Comment: @Nick Yet my answer feels ugly to me.  I'll bet Gordon Linoff would have some way of doing it without a subquery.

Comment: Thanks @Tim  for your solution.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy for your approach. It's probably the one I'll use except that I will include a IGNORE NULLS clause. I would have voted for a complete solution of yours :)

Comment: @user2008558 - Why do you need to `ignore nulls`? Can the name be `null` sometimes, and you want to exclude those rows from consideration? Otherwise (that is, if this is not a concern), I would have given the same answer as EdmCoff, not the `first_value()` answer.